# How to change size of JTable in Java?

Tags: java, jtable

I am populating a table from a database.  I have tried changing the size of the JTable in Eclipse but it still only shows part of the database table.  How do I change this?

Comment: Is your table attached to a `JScrollPane`... because that could be a potential issue.

Comment: If you post your code, we will be able to help you out more.